# Lost and found in Brussels airport?

Tags: airports, brussels, bru

Does Brussels Airport have a lost and found counter?
If yes, where can I find it and what's the schedule?

I looked it up on their website and only a form is provided.

Comment: @anomuse An item that disappeared from my luggage. Although very unlikely I want to make sure it didn't fall in the transport process and was delivered somewhere else.

Comment: There seems to be a telephone number if you prefer that  +32 900 70 000

Answer (score 2):

As the OP has discovered The Brussels Airport website has a very comprehensive page dealing with lost and found.

https://www.brusselsairport.be/en/passngr/luggage-travelinfo/lost-luggage

In answer to the question about a lost and found counter, the answer is not specifically.  In the airport, lost and found queries are dealt with by the airport information desk, which is located in the arrivals hall, and as of the date of answer weekday opening hours are 06.00 to 22.00, closing one hour earlier on weekends.

From the OP's comment about a missing item in his luggage, a baggage report with their airline's handling agent should also be filed.